# MongoDB NodeJS update removes attributes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I'm trying to update a single attribute of a user's document after the update query every attribute of the user is missing except the _id and updated attribute. What's wrong with my query?

```
dbwrapper.mongo.getConnection().then(function(db){
    db.collection('users').update({'_id' : dbwrapper.mongo.ObjID(userID)}, {'iconID':2}, function(error, resultMongo){
      console.log(error);
      if(error || !resultMongo){
        reject(error);
      }else{
        resolve(resultMongo);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how updates work with MongoDB: if the second ("update") document contains *only* **field:value** expressions, the document stored in the database will be *replaced* by the update document. This is [documented here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#replace-a-document-entirely).

If you merely want to update the `iconID` field, use [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set):

```
.update({ '_id' : ... }, { $set : { iconID : 2 }}, ...)
```